# how to check list object of element contains a string from the array string in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, listobject

How to check list object value contains any word of string array. its working for "**urgent**" word but if it comes with "**urgent abc**" then it fails.
Fields is list object.

```
 public class Fields
    {
        public int _id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public static string[] urgentWords = {"Urgent","ASAP", "Fast", "Immediately" };
 var UrgentText = data.Fields.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "urgent" && urgentWords.Contains(x.Value, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count();
```

sample data of x.Value - "Urgent ABC XYZ" //it should match and UrgentText should give 1
sample data of x.value - "review ASAP" it should match
but we are getting 0 results, as it does not contain ABC XYZ

Comment: Your `Where` isn't complete, are you doing `&` or `||`?

Comment: i have updated with and condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code *doesn't compile*; assuming that you have a collection (array, list) or enumeration of `Field`

```
IEnumerable<Field> data = ...
```

and you want to keep items that such that they contain *word* from `urgentWords` within `Value` property you can
combine Linq and Regular Expressions:

First, let's define *word* as

> Non empty sequence of Unicode letters which is not part of another word.

In this case we can use `\p{L}+` regular expression.

Second, let's have a `HashSet<string>` for `urgentWords` which is more convenient:

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> urgentWords = new (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    "Urgent", "ASAP", "Fast", "Immediately"
};
```

Then the query can be

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

var result = data
  .Where(item => "urgent".Equals(item.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  .Where(item => Regex
     .Matches(item.Value, @"\p{L}+")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Any(match => urgentWords.Contains(match.Value)))
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
var UrgentText = data.Fields.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "urgent" && urgentWords.Contains(x.Value, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count();
```

is evaluating to

Pick anything in data where  `x.Name` equals "urgent" and   `urgentWords` array contains `x.value`.

> data of x.value - "review ASAP" it should match but we are getting 0
> results, as it does not contain ABC XYZ

What is the `x.name` for  "review ASAP" ,if it isn't equal to "urgent" then that condition will always evaluate to false.

So either change to only check if `urgentWords` array contains string

```
var UrgentText = data.Fields.Where(urgentWords.Contains(x.Value, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count();
```

or change condition from `&&` to `||`

```
var UrgentText = data.Fields.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "urgent" || urgentWords.Contains(x.Value, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count();
```